# Derivative of floor function [ 1 / x ]

Tags: calculus

What is the derivative of the floor function below w.r.t  $x$ from first principle.

$\left[ \frac{1}{x} \right]$ , where $x \mapsto [x]$  represents floor function

I think the derivative only exist for values of $1/x \notin \Bbb N$ but does the derivative exit for  $0 < x < 1$?

Comment: The derivative is $0$ for all $x$ such that $1/x$ is defined and $1/x \notin \Bbb N$. For $1/x \in \Bbb N$ the limit only exists from the right, and you might say that the function has a "right derivative". See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability)

Comment: Oh yeah, fixed it

Comment: It involves Dirac Delta Function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derivative of the floor function is always $0$ except at the points where $\frac 1n{\in I}$ where the graph is discontinuous.